# How to support gestures when mediaPlayer.drawable is set?

Tags: ios, media-player, tvos, libvlc

I have a view and a subview, in which I need a player to play content.
So, when I set

```
mediaPlayer.drawable = self.playerView
```

and

```
let swipeButtonRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector3)
swipeButtonRecognizer.direction = .up
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeButtonRecognizer)
```

The tap recognizer does not seem to be working, the action on gesture does not even call. 
How to make it call? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"The tap recognizer does not seem to be working"* Which tap gesture? Your code is creating a swipe gesture.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but `VLCOpenGLES2VideoView` in libVLC is adding its own tap gesture recognizer:

> ```
> if (sys->viewContainer.window) {
>   if (sys->viewContainer.window.rootViewController) {
>       if (sys->viewContainer.window.rootViewController.view)
>           [sys->viewContainer.superview addGestureRecognizer:sys->tapRecognizer];
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Source:  [videolan/vlc/modules/video_output/ios.m](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/28cee89db4cdb0c1cf31cebb4fc84f65eeecc4c3/modules/video_output/ios.m#L527)

Maybe it is interfering with your gestures.

Note that it's adding to `sys->viewContainer.superview`.
That's `mediaPlayer.drawable.superview`, or in your case, `self.playerView.superview`.

#### Workarounds

Use either one below.

1. If your video player view does not require user interaction anyway, set `userInteractionEnabled` of its **`superview`** to `NO`.

   You may consider embedding your video player view within an extra superview, just for the sake of it.
2. If the superview is just a simple UIView, use a custom UIView instead, then override `-addGestureRecognizer` in this custom class:

   ```
   - (void)addGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
   {
       [super addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
       gestureRecognizer.enabled = false;  // Hey VLCOpenGLES2VideoView! Don't mess with my UI!
   }
   ```